# Appveyor, test reference the wrong assembly version

Tags: c#, .net, json, nuget-package-restore, appveyor

New to the Appveyor platform, so this might just be my naivety. I set up my project to build from my GitHub repo. This seems to be working, except for the tests. The code is mainly .Net 4.0, as it is supporting a legacy project - I can't move it to a later framework at the moment. Because this project is using Newtonsoft.Json already, I had to use a specific version. All code and test run locally. However, once I set up the CI (and got my head around getting the Nuget restore to happen), I still get a complete failure with the tests. They aren't doing anything spectacular. The error is pretty straight forward - the Nuget is pulling in version 6.0.8, but the build process for the tests wants to reference 8.0.0.0 according to the output:

> Discovering tests...OK vstest.console /logger:Appveyor
>   "C:\projects\debuginterface\Ratcow.Debugging.Server.Tests\bin\Debug\Ratcow.Debugging.Server.Tests.dll"
>   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26228.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. Starting
>   test execution, please wait... Failed   BasicTest_ValueTypes Error
>   Message:    Test method
>   Ratcow.Debugging.Server.Tests.MainUnitTest.BasicTest_ValueTypes threw
>   exception:  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) Stack Trace:
>       at Ratcow.Debugging.Server.DebugInterface.InstanceAsString(Object value)    at
>   Ratcow.Debugging.Server.DebugInterface.GetVariableValue(String
>   variableName) in
>   C:\projects\debuginterface\Ratcow.Debugging.Server\DebugInterface.cs:line
>   104    at
>   Ratcow.Debugging.Server.Tests.MainUnitTest.BasicTest_ValueTypes() in
>   C:\projects\debuginterface\Ratcow.Debugging.Server.Tests\MainUnitTest.cs:line
>   35

I can accept that this is probably correct - except the code is referencing 6.0.8, and so is the packages.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <packages>
     <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="net452" />
     <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="net452" />
     <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Any ideas? The last failed build with tests enabled is [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/memsom/debuginterface/build/1.0.8). It is happily building and tests are running on VS2017 on multiple desktop and laptops.

Comment: Do you use <dependentAssembly> elements in your config files?

Comment: Not at the moment. I was considering adding them, but wasn't sure is a Test project would respect them. As far as I can see, it is the Test project alone that is having issues. I've since added another project that is using a test project and that goes through with no issues.

Comment: Okay - taken the code on a machine that has never compiled it before, restored nuget packages, run build all - no issues. Then I ran the tests, again all okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Jeroen's prompt above (I was going to try this, but I didn't get time earlier before posting this question), the answer is two fold:

1. This is not Appveyor specific. My tests also failed for the exact same reasons if I ran vstest.console.exe directly upon the compiled test project. This was a big part in me fixing the issue, recreating issues is always the biggest part of fixing them.
2. As suggested, adding in a dependentAssembly declaration really worked. Here's what I added to an App.config for the test project:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
           <publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
   </configuration>
   ```

The tests now run on the command line, and having just committed the code to GitHub, it looks like the Appveyor also builds and runs the test too.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it worked once I realised there's a syntax error in the XML which caused visual studio to not even load my tests from my test project any more! :O